# Using JAXB to create reference-objects accordingly to an attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Consider the following xml:

```
<Config>
    <Paths>
        <Path reference="WS_License"/>
    </Paths>

    <Steps>
        <Step id="WS_License" title="License Agreement" />
    </Steps>
</Config>
```

The following JAXB classes:

```
public class Path {

    private String _reference;

    public String getReference() {
        return _reference;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setReference( String reference ) {
        _reference = reference;
    }

}
```

And

```
public class Step {

    private String _id;
    private String _title;

    public String getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId( String id ) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return _title;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setTitle( String title ) {
        _title = title;
    }

}
```

Instead of storing the reference in the Path object as String, I'd like to hold it as a Step object. The link between those objects is the reference and id attributes. Is the @XMLJavaTypeAdapter attribute the way to go? Could anyone be so kind to provide an example of the correct usage?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I'd also would like to do the same technique with an element.

Consider the following xml:

```
<Config>
    <Step id="WS_License" title="License Agreement">
        <DetailPanelReference reference="DP_License" />
    </Step>

    <DetailPanels>
        <DetalPanel id="DP_License" title="License Agreement" />
    </DetailPanels>
</Config>
```

The following JAXB classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Step {

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    private String _id;

    @XmlAttribute(name="title")
    private String _title;

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlElement(name="DetailPanelReference", type=DetailPanel.class)
    private DetailPanel[] _detailPanels; //Doesn't seem to work

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DetailPanel {

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    private String _id;

    @XmlAttribute(name="title")
    private String _title;

}
```

The property _detailPanels in the Step-object is empty and the link doesn't seems to work. Is there any option to create a link without creating a new JAXB object holding only the reference to the DetailPanel?

Thanks again : )!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `@XmlID` to map a property as the key and `@XmlIDREF` to map the reference to the key for this use case.

**Step**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Step {

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String _id;

}
```

**Path**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Path {

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlAttribute
    private Step _reference;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

---

**UPDATE**

> Thanks! I Completely missed your article. I've extended my question,
>   do you have any clue if this is possible too? I do not want to create
>   a class with only holding the reference, I'd like to store it inside
>   the step class.

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

If you are using MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider then you could leverage the `@XmlPath` annotation for your use case.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Step {

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlPath("DetailPanelReference/@reference")
    @XmlIDREF
    // private List<DetailPanel> _detailPanels; // WORKS
    private DetailPanel[] _detailPanels; // See bug:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/399293

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/399293
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks! I Completely missed your article. I've extended my question, do you have any clue if this is possible too? I do not want to create a class with only holding the reference, I'd like to store it inside the step class.

Comment: @MarkvanVelthoven - I have updated my answer with how you can support this use case if you are using MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider.